# Generate a random list with different numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a random list with 10 DIFFERENT numbers. This is what I have done so far:

```
from random import randint

my_list = []
i = 0
while i < 10:
    random = randint(1, 25)
    if random not in my_list:
        my_list.append(random)
        i = i + 1
    else:
        i = i
print(my_list)
```

But it does not work for some reason.

(UPDATED: My list will add the random number as a string, I need to add it as an integer)

You can use the code above, it works now.

Comment: This is just sampling without replacement. Do `random.sample(range(25), 10)`... there has to be a dupe somewhere.

Comment: What does not work here?

Comment: Sometimes (because of randint), my code generates a list with two or more same integers.

Comment: `3` and `"3"` are two different values. You add a *string* to the list, but later check if an *`int`* is present.

Comment: Oh no! So there we have the problem. I hate this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty straight-forward to me:

```
from random import randint

my_set = set()

while(len(my_set) < 10):
  my_set.add(randint(0, 100))

my_list = list(my_set)

print(my_list)
```

My random output:

```
[96, 2, 35, 9, 87, 23, 88, 57, 91, 95]
```

Comment: I don't want the list to generate two or more same integers (in your case there is two 88)

Comment: Your output itself shows that this is not what OP wants.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for the feedback. Didn't notice that part of the question and fixed it with an edit.

Comment: This is still terribly unwieldy and inefficient considering it can be done with one function call.

Comment: @coldspeed feel free to improve this community wiki answer

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks. This is a duplicate, and I'm still looking for the link.

Answer (score 0):

use `set` and then convert into `list`, because list can contain duplicate elements.

example code is

```
from random import randint

my_set = set()
while len(my_set) < 10:
  random = randint(1, 25)
  my_set.add(str(random))
print(list(my_set))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the random number to a string (for some reason) before you add it to the list. Later, you check if the *number* is a value in the list, which it never will be, because you never add a number to the list. Here's a simpler demonstration of the problem:

```
>>> 3 in ['3']
False
```

Don't bother with strings (or the no-op `i = i`).

```
from random import randint

my_list = []
i = 0
while i < 10:
    r = randint(1, 25)
    if r not in my_list:
        my_list.append(r)
        i = i + 1
print(my_list)
```

You can also use a set, which will ignore duplicates automatically.

```
my_set = {}
while len(my_set) < 10:
    my_set.add(randint(1,25))
print(my_set)
```

Or use `random.sample`, which you are reimplementing:

```
my_list = random.sample(range(1,26), 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use random library:

```
import random
mylist = [random.randint(0,100) for item in range(10)]
```

Output:
[4, 89, 40, 56, 37, 97, 73, 46, 10, 36]

> random.randint(0,100) -> here specify the range of the random number
>
> range(10) -> in your case 10 value

Hope it solves you problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to generate the random int of 10. You can also change the random number range by change the range in randint(). Moreover, you can also sum up the number in the lst by the last code I wrote.

```
from random import randint
count = 0
lst = []
for count in range(10):
    lst.append(randint(0,100))
    count += 1
print(lst)
print(sum(lst))
```